# Simple- How do i pull correct tag in BeautifulSoup/Python?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am pulling from a site --> https://www.aacr.org/patients-caregivers/cancer/breast-cancer/

I want just the paragraph info from this page (Where it starts with **There are a number of different types of breast cancer..etc**)

From my understanding, once you are in a div and class, further loops should "drill down" and scrape any info from the section/class you are in.

My code pulls paragraph info from different areas. When I run the code it gives the desired output, but as well as paragraph from a different class/section of the HTML section. (**<P class='desc'**) which is not in my stated section (class_='first-section section clearfix).

How do i pull just the desired output?

Here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


PageParagraphs = []
url='https://www.aacr.org/patients-caregivers/cancer/breast-cancer/'
r=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
section=soup.find_all('div',class_='first-section section clearfix')
for item in section:
      paragraphs=soup.find_all('p')
      print(paragraphs)
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only get the first `<p>` tag using a CSS Selector:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.aacr.org/patients-caregivers/cancer/breast-cancer/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

print(soup.select_one('.first-section p').text)
```

---

Or using your above code, use `find()` to only get the first `<p>` tag instead of `find_all()`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.aacr.org/patients-caregivers/cancer/breast-cancer/"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
section = soup.find_all("div", class_="first-section section clearfix")[0]
print(section.find("p").text)
```

**Edit** to get all paragraph tags:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.aacr.org/patients-caregivers/cancer/breast-cancer/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.select('.first-section p'):
    print(tag.text)
```

Output:

```
There are a number of different types of breast cancer. The most common form of breast cancer is ductal carcinoma, which begins in the cells of the ducts. Cancer that begins in the lobes or lobules is called lobular carcinoma and is more often found in both breasts than are other types of breast cancer. Inflammatory breast cancer is an uncommon type of breast cancer in which the breast is warm, red, and swollen.
Hereditary breast cancer makes up from 5 percent to 10 percent of all breast cancer diagnoses. Women who have certain gene mutations, such as a BRCA1 or BRCA2 mutation, have an increased risk of developing breast cancer and are also at increased risk of ovarian cancer. Other risk factors include estrogen (made in the body), dense breast tissue, age at menstruation and first birth, taking hormones for symptoms of menopause, obesity, and not getting enough exercise.
The National Cancer Institute’s Surveillance, Epidemiology, and End Results (SEER) Program estimates that in 2020 276,480 women in the United States will be diagnosed with breast cancer and 42,170 will die of the disease. From 2010 to 2016, the five-year survival rate for those diagnosed with breast cancer was 90.0 percent.  
Men can also develop breast cancer, making up slightly less than 1 percent of those diagnosed each year. Radiation exposure, high levels of estrogen, and a family history of breast cancer can increase a man’s risk of the disease.

Source: National Cancer Institute
```

**Edit 2** without using a CSS Selector:

```
for tag in soup.find_all(class_='first-section section clearfix'):
    for p in tag.find_all('p'):
        print(p.text)
```

Comment: How about the remaining paragraphs? And why did it pull information from desc class when that isnt class isnt stated in the line above my for loop code

Comment: For the second solution, why did you put a [0] at the end of 2nd to last line? It also does not get the remaining paragraphs

Comment: @VoidS I put a `[0]` because `find_all()` returns a list.
See my edit to get all paragraphs

Comment: Im not familiar with CSS, I like your second solution, -> to go off of it, how do we get the remaining paragraphs using 2nd method approach?

Comment: thank you very much and thanks for your patience ! works great

Answer (score 0):

If you want the paragraphs with content you could use the following with bs4 4.7.1 +. I use :not to exclude empty and right side box paragraphs. I assumed you didn't want source as the end. If you want the source para then remove `, :has(span)`

```
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print('\n'.join([i.text for i in soup.select(".content p:not(:empty, :has(span))")]))
```